# Need to understand Short term and long term fuel trim numbers

Tags: fuel-trims

I have the following numbers with idle and at 2000 rpm.  What would this conclude?  I had a O2 sensor check engine light but even after replacement it had the same engine light after resetting.

[image: IDLE]
[image: 2000RPM]

Comment: What is the explanation given - that device surely contains help files.. good ones usually do...

Comment: Which vehicle is this? And where is the long term fuel trim for Bank 2? Without it the picture isn't complete. And do you know what the O2-sensor-related code is?

Comment: This is for nissan altima 2006 3.5sl.  The code is P2A00 which I replaced (Air Fuel ratio sensor) for bank 1.

Comment: Yah, would need LTFT2 to get the complete picture, but just looking at LTFT1, it is all out of whack. The system is trying to compensate for some kind of irregularity. Might possibly be unmetered air getting into the system or a leak in the exhaust before the front O2 sensor causing a false reading, pushing the computer to enrich the fuel trims.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Based on readings - it seems like I have a leak.  My question to you is - would a Bank 1 Sensor 1 engine light come up(P2A00) could there is an leak near catalytic converter?  Or would it be in the area of exhaust manifold(vacuum).

Comment: I'd suggest it's somewhere upstream of the primary O2 sensor (either or both sides), so would not include the cat or the downstream O2 sensor. You'd have to pull up live data on the O2 sensors themselves to see what they are seeing.